# Does Ashe extra gold passive on minion kills, stacks with Twisted Fate´s gold passive?

Tags: league-of-legends

Ashe's passive skill `Hawkshot` gives her extra gold per kill; similar Twisted Fate's passive grants +2 gold per kill for everyone on the team. If an Ashe is on the same team with a Twisted Fate, will these bonuses stack together?

Answer (score 2):

They stack with each other, as it's not an exclusive buff. Enjoy the extra gold.

Answer (score 1):

yes they do stack together so at level 5 hawkshot you will get the +5 and the +2 bonus per kill

Answer (score 0):

it doesnt "stack" but it will show you getting Ashe's passive gold from her E as well as the extra gold from TF's passive. so in theory yes. you get all the gold you would hope for from those two abilities.